EDB Replication behavior
I'm using EDB Replication with 3 postgres databases in MMR Replication.
Let's call them Node1, Node2 and Node3. I have a table "todo" on each one of them and I'm getting some weird behavior.
If I add a new row on "todo" of Node1, it replicates on Node2 and Node3 just fine. The expected behavior.
If I add a new row on "todo" of Node2, it replicates on Node1 but Node3 is not getting any changes at all.
Finally if I add a new row on "todo" of Node3, it doesn't replicate on any of the other Nodes.
The master node is Node2, which is creating even more confusion, at least if the master database was Node1 it might've made some sense. The PC I'm working on is Node2 and it is the master with the EDB Replication software. Node1 and Node3 are on completely different buildings. EDB Replication software has all Nodes installed and shows no errors, I can view their databases and tables just fine.
Any ideas what might be going on here?

Because I'm using 3 PostgreSQL databases
